# How can I resolve this recursive overflow?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory, recursion

```
#define MIN -2147483648


long max(long x,long y)
{

    long m=x;
    if(y>x)
        m=y;
    return m;
}

long f(int x,int y,int **p)
{

    long result;
    if(x<0||y<0)
        result = MIN;
    else 
        if(x==0&&y==0)
            result = p[0][0];
        else
            result = max(f(x-1,y,p),f(x,y-1,p))+p[x][y];
    return result; 
}

int main(void)
{

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int** p = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)    
            scanf("%d",p[i]+j);
    }
    printf("haha\n");
    printf("%ld\n",f(n-1,n-1,p));   
    return 0;
}
```

when I assign 10 to `n`, it works well.But when I assign 20 to `n`, there's no result put out. I googled it and I guessed that the error may be a recursive overflow. So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What does it compute?

Comment: This seems not a recursive overflow but a combinatorial explosion. Consider using another method like dynamic programming.

Comment: `#define MIN -2147483648` seems bad because it may not be possible minimum value and may cause integer overflow. You should use `LONG_MIN` from `limits.h` instead.

Comment: Your code gives me one compiler error and one warning (MSVC). First `max` is already a macro defined in `stdlib.h`, and `result = MIN;` gives "warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned"

Comment: ...the number `-2147483648` does not occur in MSVC library headers, instead it is `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)`

Comment: Curious, did you try `n` as 11, 12, 13 ... or maybe 15 and if that worked 17 ...?

Comment: WRT `-2147483648` as the value of `MIN`: `-2147483648` is a (positive) number `2147483648` negated by the `-` operator, rather than a simple negative number.  If `2147483648` is too large for signed `long int`, MSVC (and possibly others) may treat it as `unsigned long int`... which is why `(-2147483647 - 1)` would be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a very large number of recursive calls.  At each level, you make twice the number of calls as the prior level.  So when N is 20, you're making 2^20 = 1048576 function calls.  That takes a long time.

Most of these calls keep recomputing the same values over and over again.  Rather that recomputing these values, calculate them only once.

Here's a non-recursive method of doing this:

```
long f(int x,int y,int **p)
{
    long **p2;
    int i, j;

    p2 = malloc(sizeof(long *)*(x+1));
    for (i=0;i<=x;i++) {
        p2[i] = malloc(sizeof(long)*(y+1));
        for (j=0;j<=y;j++) {
            if (i==0 && j==0) {
                p2[i][j] = p[i][j];
            } else if (i==0) {
                p2[i][j] = p2[i][j-1] + p[i][j];
            } else if (j==0) {
                p2[i][j] = p2[i-1][j] + p[i][j];
            } else {
                p2[i][j] = max(p2[i-1][j], p2[i][j-1]) + p[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return p2[x][y];
}
```

EDIT:

If you still want a recursive solution, you can do the following.  This only makes recursive calls if the necessary values have not yet been computed.

```
long f(int x,int y,int **p)
{
    static long**p2=NULL;
    int i, j;

    if (!p2) {
        p2 = malloc(sizeof(long*)*(x+1));
        for (i=0;i<=x;i++) {
            p2[i] = malloc(sizeof(long)*(y+1));
            for (j=0;j<=y;j++) {
                p2[i][j] = MIN;
            }
        }
    }

    if (x==0 && y==0) {
        p2[x][y] = p[x][y];
    } else if (x==0) {
        if (p2[x][y-1] == MIN) {
            p2[x][y-1] = f(x,y-1,p);
        }
        p2[x][y] = p2[x][y-1] + p[x][y];
    } else if (y==0) {
        if (p2[x-1][y] == MIN) {
            p2[x-1][y] = f(x-1,y,p);
        }
        p2[x][y] = p2[x-1][y] + p[x][y];
    } else {
        if (p2[x][y-1] == MIN) {
            p2[x][y-1] = f(x,y-1,p);
        }
        if (p2[x-1][y] == MIN) {
            p2[x-1][y] = f(x-1,y,p);
        }
        p2[x][y] = max(p2[x-1][y], p2[x][y-1]) + p[x][y];
    }

    return p2[x][y];
}
```

Comment: Bingo!  I was just writing this up, but I like your code structure better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which compiler you are using. Look into how to increase stack size for your program. However, even if you get it to work for n=20, there will be a limit (may not be far from n=20) due to combinatorial explosion as mentioned in previous comment.

For n > 0, each call to f(n) calls f(n-1) twice. So calling f(n) = calling 2*fn(n-1)

For n = 20, that is 2^20 calls. Each call returns a long. If long is 8 bytes = 2^3, then you have at least 2^23 bytes on the stack.

**EDIT**

Actually, according to the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld), the linker controls the stack size.
You can try increasing stack size and implement more efficient algorithm as proposed by different answers

To increase stack size with ld (the GNU linker)

--stack reserve

--stack reserve,commit

Specify the number of bytes of memory to reserve (and optionally commit) to be used as stack for this program. The default is 2Mb reserved, 4K committed. [This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker]

Comment: I use GCC compiler.